# upgrading from istio-1.4 to 1.15 borke pgadmin statefull set

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, istio, pgadmin-4

- Kubernetes 1.22
- Istio 1.4.5 upgrade istio to 1.15.0

Can't when trying to connect to pgadmin4 via istio VS I am getting following error inside web browser

> upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. reset
> reason: connection failure, transport failure reason: delayed connect
> error: 111

Connection works when trying kubectl port-forward to service

Answer (score 0):

Checked the `PGADMIN_LISTEN_ADDRESS` inside the stateful-set which was pointing to 127.0.0.1.

After change to 0.0.0.0 everything works

```
    - name: PGADMIN_LISTEN_ADDRESS
      value: 0.0.0.0
```

Most probably this happened due to switch inside the traffic policy which was Local before and update changed it.

```
internalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
```